# Eventhandling in combination with the .map function

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-props, react-functional-component

Let's say I have a parent component like this:

```js
export default class InputView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nr: [2, 3],
    };
  }

 handleDel = () => {
    console.log('klick');
  };

 render() {
    const elements = this.state.nr.map(inputPdf(nr));
    return (
      <div>
         {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The function inputPdf() creates another component;

```js
const inputPdf = (nr) => {
  return (
    <div class="card">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={this.props.handleDel()}>      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And now I want to use the function handleDel() in my child component.

How to get this running...?

Comment: Please add the full code that you are trying to get to work. You use a function named `input` but you show a function called `inputPdf `. Are these functions the same (so your example code is wrong)? Are these in the same file? You'll have to give some detail so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in code. But if you want to go with your way. It should be like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

class InputView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nr: [2, 3],
    };
  }

 handleDel = () => {
    console.log('klick');
  };

 render() {
    const elements = this.state.nr.map((data) => inputPdf(data,this.handleDel));
    return (
      <div>
         {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const inputPdf = (nr,onClick) => {
  return (
    <div class="card">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={onClick}> 
      {nr}     </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputView/>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txqp8k

Issue in code:

1. Component should have capital name
2. Instead of rendering {elements} you can directly render component like this inside render

Better way:

```
  return this.state.nr.map(data => <InputPdf onClick={this.handleDel} nr={nr}/>)
    //where
   const InputPdf = ({nr,onClick}) => {
    return (
      <div class="card">
       <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={onClick}> 
         {nr}     </button>
      </div>
     );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how we can do it.

```
export default class InputView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nr: [2, 3],
    };
  }

  handleDel = (indexToDelete) => {
    console.log("klick");
  };
  render() {
    const elements = this.state.nr.map((elem, index) => {
      return <InputPdf item={elem} index={index} handleDel={handleDel} />
    });
    return <div>{elements}</div>;
  }
}

const InputPdf = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div class="card">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="close"
        aria-label="Close"
        onClick={() => props.handleDel(props.index)}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Okay, I forget to mention, that i want to manipulate the array nr[2,3]. For Example delet the 2.